# How to print to console in a Python WebJob on Microsoft Azure?

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure, azure-webjobs

How do I print debug information from a Python script to the Azure WebJob Console?

I have successfully [deployed a continuously running Python WebJob on Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/), I have included my packages, and when the console showed some errors I've been able to fix them and [re-upload through FTP](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/74215124623/deploy-azure-webjobs/#.VjIBhIRiBgo).

Right now, the console (Azure WebJobs Dashboard) shows that my script is running.

`[10/29/2015 10:42:53 > a19167: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
[10/29/2015 10:42:53 > a19167: SYS INFO] Job directory change detected: Job file 'run.py' timestamp differs between source and working directories.
[10/29/2015 10:42:58 > a19167: SYS INFO] Run script 'run.py' with script host - 'PythonScriptHost'
[10/29/2015 10:42:58 > a19167: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running`

However, my script is littered with `print()` statements which don't show. I have also tried `sys.stdout.write()` and `sys.stderr.write()` but they don't work either.

UPDATE: Print messages do show! They just appear in bulk, once every few hours...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To immediately see your log statements in the Azure WebJobs Dashboard, simply call sys.stdout.flush()

Flushing the console output makes sense after intializing the web job, and after processing a single task (e.g. processing a queue message).